# Doctrine2 ORM OneToOne not working UPDATE changed to ManyToMany but not fully working

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have 2 tables called Advert and User. The User Id gets written into the Advert Table. I have now created a third table called Bookmark. The table got 2 columns, advert_id and user_id. When I see an Advert I like, I can add a Bookmark to be able to find it easier in my Private Section. When I am in my Private Section to see my Bookmarks, I want to see the Advert Details straight away, so in my Repository I want to create a Join to read the information from the Advert Table. I thought this will be a OneToOne Relationship. I also have to make sure that if the Advert gets deleted, then all the Bookmarks need to be deleted, so I thought its a Bi-directional relationship. So I have below:

**Entity/Bookmark.php**

```
 /**
 * Bookmark
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="bookmark")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\BookmarkRepository")
 */
class Bookmark
{
 /**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="advert_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Advert", mappedBy="bookmark")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $advertId;

/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 private $userId;


 public function setAdvertId($advertId)
 {
    $this->advertId = $advertId;
    return $this;
 }


 public function getAdvertId()
 {
    return $this->advertId;
 }


 public function setUserId($userId)
 {
    $this->userId = $userId;
    return $this;
 }


 public function getUserId()
 {
    return $this->userId;
 }
```

**Entity\Advert.php**

```
/** Advert
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */

class Advert
{
  /**
   * @var integer
   *
   * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
   * @ORM\Id
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
   */
    private $id;

 /**
   * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Bookmark", inversedBy="advert")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="advert_id")
   **/
    private $bookmark;

public function setBookmark($bookmark)
{
    $this->bookmark = $bookmark;
    return $this;
}


public function getBookmark()
{
    return $this->bookmark;
}



public function addBookmark($bookmark)
{
    $this->bookmark->add($bookmark);
}


public function removeBookmark($bookmark)
{
    $this->bookmark->removeElement($bookmark);   
}
```

**Advert\Repository\Advert\Repository.php**

```
class BookmarkRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function getBookmarksByUserIds($userId)
  {
    $query =$this->_em->getRepository($this->getEntityName())->createQueryBuilder('b')
                            ->join('b.advertId', 'a')
                            ->andWhere('a.userId=:userid')
                            ->setParameter('userid',$userId)       
            ;
    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```

What do I do wrong or where is my missunderstanding? I get the Error Message:

*Advert\Entity\Bookmark has no association named advertId*

As I said, the table Bookmark gets only filled, when I click on "Add Advert to Bookmarks". I need a Join to be able to display the Advert Details when I click on "Show my Bookmarks" and if an Advert or a User gets deleted, all Bookmarks need to be removed from the Bookmark table. Is this a OneToOne Bi-directional relationship and what is wrong?

**UPDATE 1  BELOW NOT WORKING**

I have updated the 2 Files below, but I do not get any Bookmarks shown. Instead I should see a list of Bookmarked adverts plus the advert details. I have not even tried yet to get my Service to "Bookmark Advert" or the method to check if an Advert is bookmarked working again. I got it working before, but I guess I am just really confused now.

**AdvertController.php**

```
public function watchlistAction()
{
    $user_id = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity()->getId();
    $adverts = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\User')->findBookmarksByUserId($user_id);
        return new ViewModel(array(
            'adverts' => $adverts,
        ));
}
```

**Repository\UserRepository.php**

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{

  public function findBookmarksByUserId($userId)
  {
      $query =$this->_em->getRepository($this->getEntityName())->createQueryBuilder('b')
                            ->join('b.bookmarks', 'a')
                            ->join('b.adverts', 'c')
                ->andWhere('a.user=:userid')
                ->setParameter('userid',$userId)       
            ;
      return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
  }
```

**UPDATE 2  BELOW WORKING**

You were right, I don't need the UserRepository Query see the List of Bookmarked Adverts. I just had to change the

**AdvertController.php**

```
public function watchlistAction()
{
        $user_id = $this->zfcUserAuthentication()->getIdentity()->getId();
        // get User by reference (no queries executed)
        $user = $this->getEntityManager()->getReference('Advert\Entity\User' , $user_id);
        $adverts = $user->getBookmarks();

        return new ViewModel(array(
            'adverts' => $adverts,
        ));
}
```

Good news also, in the moment I delete an Advert, the Bookmark gets automatically removed in the Bookmark Database table. Now I only have to find out how to add the Bookmark, so I will have to change my Service. As soon I get this working I will update this post for others to see.

**UPDATE 3 BELOW NOT WORKING**

Unfortunately I do not get the below 3 Methods in my Service working. I obviously have to now pick 1 record, to either check the Status (Bookmarked already or not), remove the Bookmark (defined by advertId) or add a Bookmark (defined by advertId)

```
public function checkAdvertBookmarkStatus($advertId)
{
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();  
    // get User by reference (no queries executed)
    $user = $this->getEntityManager()->getReference('Advert\Entity\User' , $userId);

    $bookmarkStatus = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\User')
                                         ->findOneBy(array('advert' => $advertId, 'userId' => $userId));

    return $bookmarkStatus;
}  

   public function saveAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    $bookmark = new UserEntity();
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();

 //   $bookmark->addBookmark($advertId);
    $bookmark->setAdvertId($advertId);
    $bookmark->setUserId($userId);

    # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}


public function removeAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    $bookmark = new UserEntity();
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();
    $bookmark = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Bookmark')
                                         ->findOneBy(array('advertId' => $advertId, 'userId' => $userId));

    # remove bookmmark from tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->remove($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();

}
```

I suppose the answer is in the Tutorial, which I keep reading, but I do not understand it fully. I was able to add Bookmarks before, when I was using the BookmarkEntity, but I have no idea how to do it via the UserEntity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A OneToOne relationship would be the wrong choice here, this would mean that a user can bookmark only one advert and that an advert can only be bookmarked by one user. Because a user should be able to bookmark many adverts and an advert should be bookmarked by many users, you need a ManyToMany relationship.

You idea to create a mapping table bookmarks is not wrong if you work with a database. However, you don't need to create it as an entity in Doctrine. You can simply add Adverts in an association called bookmarks in User to display the bookmarked Adverts and vice versa:

**User Entity:**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="bookmarks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bookmarks",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $bookmarks;
```

**Advert Entity**

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application\Entity\User", mappedBy="bookmarks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bookmarks",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $bookmarks;
```

You might want to read this article, too:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html

**Edit: How to add and remove bookmarks**

Associations in Doctrine are something entirely different from fields, although both are properties in your Entity. To handle bookmarks you add or remove the Advert Entity in your User Entity directly. For example:

```
$bookmarks = $user->getBookmarks();
$bookmarks[] = $advert;
```

This would add a bookmark to the user and will be stored as soon as you `persist` and `flush`. To make this even easier, you can define `remover` and `adder`:

Use statements:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
```

and the code:

```
/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function addBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
    foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
        $this->bookmarks->add($bookmark);
    }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
    foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
        $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
    }
}
```

You can now remove and add adverts given in collection like this:

```
$user->addBookmarks(new ArrayCollection(array($advert)));
```

It is always recommended to define `adder` and `remover` in toMany relationships, because many Doctrine components will need them, for example the very useful DoctrineObject, a hydrator used by DoctrineModule for Zend 2

Comment: Thank you very much. I think my idea with OneToOne occured because I came from "a User bookmarks an Advert" so I created an Entity for Bookmarks and in my Service I set the Bookmark. This made perfect sense. From there I thought now I have to join the Advert Table... I will try your solution, does it mean I have to remove the Bookmark Entity and have to somehow change the Advert Entity to add a Bookmark?

Comment: Creating a database schema is something very abstract, we all make mistakes here.
And yes, you can delete your Bookmark Entity, but you don't need to change the Advert Entity in order to add a bookmark. I will edit the answer to explain how to add and remove bookmarks

Comment: Thanks so much for your help !! I am trying to implement your solution, but one more question, does it mean I have to remove my BookmarkRepository as well? Right now I get lots of Errors. I always created an Entity per DB Table plus a Repository. Would my Queries for the Bookmarks now all go into the Advert Repositories instead?

Comment: This highly depends on your queries. If you want to get the bookmarks of a user, you just get the user by id and call `getBookmarks` and if you want to get the users who bookmarked an advert, you'd just get that advert and do the same. Keep in mind that bookmarks themselves don't exist anymore - only the link between User and Advert. Because your structure has changed, many queries won't work anymore and I'd just try to write them again.

Comment: You are right, nothing works anymore. Have to admit that I am pretty confused now. As I said, when I clicked on the "Add Bookmark" I used the Query inside the BookmarkRepository, which used the Bookmark Entity. If I understand right, then I now delete both files and instead enter the Query into the UserRepository. The same would be for the "show my Bookmarks (with the details from the Advert)". The Query now gets entered into the UserRepository.  Puuh

Comment: Those two action are actually very simple and you don't need a query at all. To add a bookmark: I'm sure you have your User somewhere in your project, if he's logged in. If not, you can find it by the ID. Add the advert to the user and `flush()` the user, then the advert is added. Second, to show your users bookmarks: Get the User entity and you will automatically have all the bookmarks with `getBookmarks`. Maybe you want to read this tutorial again:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#starting-with-the-product