# Doctrine2 ORM Access ManyToMany Join Table

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

A follow up to my previous question

> [Doctrine2 ORM OneToOne not working UPDATE changed to ManyToMany but not fully working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759752/doctrine2-orm-onetoone-not-working-update-changed-to-manytomany-but-not-fully-wo).

I accepted the very helpful answer given, since it pointed me in the right direction. Unfortunately, I struggle to get the rest working, but since the question got too long and confusing, I start a new question.

I have a page where user can write adverts. User can also bookmark adverts they like to see them later in their User Section.

I have got 3 Database tables

```
advert (id, advert_title....)
user (id, user_name....)
bookmarks (advert_id, user_id)
```

As adviced in my previous question, I have created 2 Entities, Advert and User Entity (see below)

**Advert.php**

```
namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use DateTime;
use Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject;

/** Advert
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */

class Advert
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
     private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\User", mappedBy="bookmarks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bookmarks",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
    private $bookmarks;


    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $this->categories = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->advertCreated = new \DateTime("now");
    }

/** 
 * Set ID 
 * 
 * @param integer $id 
 * @return Advert 
 */ 
    public function setId($id) 
    { 
        $this->id = $id; 
        return $this; 
    }

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

 /**
 * Set bookmark
 *
 * @param  $bookmark
 * @return bookmark
 */
    public function setBookmark($bookmark)
    {
        $this->bookmark = $bookmark;
        return $this;
    }


/**
 * Get bookmark
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
    public function getBookmark()
    {
        return $this->bookmarks;
    }


/**
 * @param Collection $bookmark
 */
    public function addBookmark($bookmarks)
    {
        $this->bookmarks->add($bookmarks);
    }

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmark
 */
    public function removeBookmark($bookmarks)
    {
        $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmarks);     
    }
}
```

**User.php**

```
namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ZfcUser\Entity\User as ZfcUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


/**
 * User
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\UserRepository")
 */

class User extends ZfcUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="bookmarks", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="bookmarks",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
 private $bookmarks;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->bookmarks = new ArrayCollection();  
}

public function getBookmarks() {
     return $this->bookmarks;
}

/**
* @param Collection $bookmarks
*/
public function addBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->bookmarks->add($bookmark);
   }
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
   }
}  
}
```

I have now got a Service to check if an Advert is already Bookmarked, to delete a Bookmark or to set a Bookmark. That means I have to enter the UserId and AdvertId direct into the Join Table Bookmarks. But how do I do that, if I don't have the Bookmark Entity with the setUserId and setAdvertId?

Here is my Service so far the last 2 methods (save and remove) show what I used before I removed the Bookmark Entity. How can I now read the Join Table to check if a Bookmark already exists so check for userId and advertId? And again how would I access this table to delete the Bookmark directly? The Bookmark gets deleted if an Advert gets removed by the owner which is great, but obviously a User also needs to be able to delete just a Bookmark. How do I achieve this?

**BookmarkAdvertService.php**

```
public function checkAdvertBookmarkStatus($advertId)
{
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();  
    $advert = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Advert\Entity\Advert', $advertId);
    $bookmarkStatus= $advert->getBookmark();
    return $bookmarkStatus;
}

public function saveAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    //this is what I used before
    $bookmark = new BookmarkEntity();
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();

    // $bookmark->addBookmark($advertId); ??? like this
    $bookmark->setAdvertId($advertId);
    $bookmark->setUserId($userId);

    # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}


public function removeAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    // this is what I used before
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();
    $bookmark = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Bookmark')
                                         ->findOneBy(array('advertId' => $advertId, 'userId' => $userId));

    # remove bookmmark from tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->remove($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}
```

**UPDATE 1 NOT WORKING**

I get 2 Error Messages:

`get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given`

```
vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException.php:96

Message:

Class '' does not exist
```

**Advert\Service\BookmarkAdvertService.php**

```
class BookmarkAdvertService 
{

  public function saveAdvertBookmark($advert)
  {
    $user = $this->getUserEntity()->getId(); 

    # create a new, empty entity
    $bookmark = new \Advert\Entity\Bookmark();
    $bookmark->setUser($user);
    $bookmark->setAdvert($advert);
     # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
  }
```

**Advert/Entity/Bookmark.php**

```
namespace Advert\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/** Bookmark
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="bookmarks")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\BookmarkRepository")
 */
class Bookmark
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="bookmark")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $advert;

/** 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookmark")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $user;


public function setAdvert($advert)
{
    $this->advert = $advert;
    return $this;
}

public function getAdvert()
{
    return $this->advert;
}


public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}

public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}    
}
```

**Advert\Entity\advert.php**

```
namespace Advert\Entity;
use Advert\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
/** Advert
 * 
 * @ORM\Table(name="advert")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\AdvertRepository")
 */
class Advert
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bookmark", mappedBy="advert", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bookmarks;

public function setBookmark($bookmark)
{
    $this->bookmark = $bookmark;
    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get bookmark
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection
 */
public function getBookmarks()
{
    return $this->bookmarks;
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
  foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
    $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
}
}
```

**Advert\Entity\User.php**

```
namespace Advert\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use ZfcUser\Entity\User as ZfcUser;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Advert\Repository\UserRepository")
 */

class User extends ZfcUser
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
 protected $id;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Bookmark", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $bookmarks;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->bookmarks = new ArrayCollection();
}


public function getBookmarks() 
{
     return $this->bookmarks;
}

/**
* @param Collection $bookmarks
*/
public function addBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->bookmarks->add($bookmark);
   }
}

/**
* @param Collection $bookmarks
*/
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
   }
}
```

**UPDATE 2 WORKING**

```
public function saveAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    $userId = $this->getUserEntity()->getId(); 
    $user = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Advert\Entity\User', $userId);
    $advert = $this->getEntityManager()->find('Advert\Entity\Advert', $advertId);
     # create a new, empty entity
    $bookmark = new \Advert\Entity\Bookmark();
    $bookmark->setUser($user);
    $bookmark->setAdvert($advert);
     # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
    $this->getEntityManager()->persist($bookmark);
    $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
}


public function removeAdvertBookmark($advert)
{
    $user = $this->getUserEntity()->getId();  
    $advert = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('Advert\Entity\Bookmark')
                                         ->findOneBy(array('advert' => $advert, 'user' => $user));
    if ($advert !== NULL){

         # write new bookmmark to database tbl bookmark
        $this->getEntityManager()->remove($advert);
        $this->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping seems wrong.
It seems to me that your bookmark itself is also an entity. That entity has one `User` and one `Advert`. Those two combined create a composite key.

So the relationship from `User` to `Bookmark` is one-to-many. And bookmark to user many-to-one.

The relationship from `Advert` to `Bookmark` is one-to-many and from `Bookmark` to `Advert` many-to-one.

Your `Bookmark` entity should look something like this:

```
class Bookmark
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="bookmarks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="advert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $advert;

    /** 
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\User", inversedBy="bookmarks")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @param Advert $advert
     * @return self
     */
    public function setAdvert(Advert $advert)
    {
        $this->advert = $advert;
        $advert->addBookMark($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Advert
     */
    public function getAdvert()
    {
        return $this->advert;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @return self
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $user->addBookMark($this);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }    
}
```

Then in your `User`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\BookMark", mappedBy="user", cascade={"remove"})
 */
 private $bookmarks;

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getBookmarks() 
{
     return $this->bookmarks;
}

/**
 * @param BookMark $bookmark
 */
public function addBookmark(BookMark $bookmark)
{
   $this->bookmarks->add($bookmark);
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function addBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->addBookMark($bookmark);
   }
}

/**
 * @param BookMark $bookmark
 */
public function removeBookmark(BookMark $bookmark)
{
   $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->removeBookmark($bookmark);
   }
}
```

And in your `Advert`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Advert\Entity\BookMark", mappedBy="advert", cascade={"remove"})
 */
 private $bookmarks;

/**
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getBookmarks() 
{
     return $this->bookmarks;
}

/**
 * @param BookMark $bookmark
 */
public function addBookmark(BookMark $bookmark)
{
   $this->bookmarks->add($bookmark);
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function addBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->addBookMark($bookmark);
   }
}

/**
 * @param BookMark $bookmark
 */
public function removeBookmark(BookMark $bookmark)
{
   $this->bookmarks->removeElement($bookmark);
}

/**
 * @param Collection $bookmarks
 */
public function removeBookmarks(Collection $bookmarks)
{
   foreach ($bookmarks as $bookmark) {
       $this->removeBookmark($bookmark);
   }
}
```

In your service:

```
/**
 * @param int $advertId
 */
public function saveAdvertBookmark($advertId)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getEntityManager():
    $user = $this->getUserEntity(); 

    $advert = $entityManager->find('Advert\Entity\Advert', $advertId):
    $bookmark = new \Advert\Entity\Bookmark();
    $bookmark->setUser($user);
    $bookmark->setAdvert($advert);

    $entityManager->persist($bookmark);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

To remove all bookmarks when you remove `User` or `Advert` simply add  `cascade={"remove"}` on your bookmarks relationship in those entities.